# Kernel memory leak detection

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

How are memory leaks identified in Kernel. Not sure if Valgrind can be used in this case.

Comment: There were ways of detecting memory leaks before valgrind. E.g. compilation with as special memory allocation function with some extra overhead to keep track of non-released blocks. You would write some source line identifying ID in the header of these blocks and keep track of them in a linked list. At the end what was not freed (and removed from the list) was a leak.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910563/how-to-determine-if-a-linux-kernel-module-is-leaking-memory

Answer (score 3):

You have to have a kernel source with kernel hacking enabled. Then switch on `CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK` and compile your kernel.

When you have that running:

```
echo scan >  /sys/kernel/debug/kmemleak
```

to switch it on and

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/kmemleak
```

for a report.

Original proposal reviewed on [lwn.net](https://lwn.net/Articles/187979/)

There is a `kmemleak.txt` in the kernel source code tree under Documentation